# Replicating findall in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm attempting to have some code that will return a single list of positions/indices where elements are found in some base list.  After much searching, copying, tweaking, etc. The following code is what I have gotten to so far.

It works in SWISH, but requires that I hit next several times before I finally get a single list with all the positions of the searched for element.

How might I have it do all the answers before sending/printing back the resulting list?

```
pos([E|_],E,I,P) :-  P = I.
pos([E|T],E,I,[P|Pt]) :- I1 is I+1, pos(T,E,I1,Pr), Pt = Pr, P = I.
pos([H|T],E,I,P) :- H\=E, I1 is I+1, pos(T,E,I1,Pr), P = Pr.

find(X,P):- a(L),pos(L,X,1,Pr), P = Pr.

a([2,1,4,5,3,2,6,2,1,21,2,1,4,7,4,3,5,2,4,6,8,2,1,37,3,2]).
```

Results:

```
?- find(2,X)
X = 1
X = [1|6]
X = [1, 6|8]
X = [1, 6, 8|11]
X = [1, 6, 8, 11|18]
X = [1, 6, 8, 11, 18|22]
X = [1, 6, 8, 11, 18, 22|26]
```

Comment: Using `findall/3` as you question suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible solutions.
If you want to keep your code, you should write something like this (basically, you do need to call again the predicate when you find a match)

```
find_in([],_,_,[]).
find_in([El|TL],El,Pos,[Pos|T]):- !,
    P1 is Pos + 1,
    find_in(TL,El,P1,T).
find_in([_|T],El,Pos,L):-
    P1 is Pos + 1,
    find_in(T,El,P1,L).

find_pos(El,LPos):-
    a(L),
    find_in(L,El,1,LPos).

?- find_pos(2,X).
X = [1, 6, 8, 11, 18, 22, 26]
```

I've used the cut, but you can avoid it using `\=` (as you have done in your question).
If you can use built in predicates (`nth0/3` or something similar and `findall/3`), there is a more compact solution:

```
find_pos(El,LPos):-
    a(L),
    findall(I,nth1(I,L,El),LPos).

?- find_pos(2,X).
X = [1, 6, 8, 11, 18, 22, 26]
```

Comment: Thanks,  I had both
   `pos([],_,_,[]).`
and

   `pos([E|_],E,I,P) :-  P = I.`

Before I had my other two pos lines resolved.  In that process I deleted the former rather than the latter, and it appears just swapping which one I deleted (after getting the second two lines working) would have done the trick.